# ClipRaster with three inputs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster, clip

1) How can I clip raster with checked "Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry?

I don't want to specify X, Y Min/Max for the Output Extent.  I want to run a simple Clip Raster script that includes 3 inputs (tobeclipped.tif, outputextent.shp, and outputraster.tif)

```
import arcpy
arcpy.Clip_management(
    "C:\tobeclipped.tif","1679872.292545 329909.492583 563751.298733 1399220.865851",
    "C:\output.tif", "#", "#", "NONE", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use `clipping_geometry = True` as in the following example.

```
import arcpy

shp = r'C:\temp\myshp.shp'
raster = r'C:\temp\someRaster.tif'

arcpy.Clip_management (raster, 
                       in_template_dataset = shp, 
                       out_raster =  r'C:\temp\outRaster.tif', 
                       clipping_geometry = True)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, @Aaron.  I actually needed it to border the geometry not clip to it's max extent.  Sorry I wasn't very clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "border the geometry"?

Comment: I have a large (.tif) raster that overlays a smaller county border (.shp), and I need to clip the raster so it mirrors the border of the county file.

Comment: The script that I provided does just that.

Comment: Ok.  I must be doing something wrong.  Its providing a square image (.tif) that extends to the maximum north, south, east, west boundaries.  I'm not getting it to clip to the actual border of the .shp file though.

Comment: I just tested this again and it works.  Are the shp and raster files in the same projection on your end?

Comment: For every directory I select for out_raster, the output shows in the manner I described.  Only when I allow it to save to the Default.gbd will it clip correctly.  I've never seen that before.

Comment: Finally figured it out.  Saving to a directory was causing the problem.  When the output is saved to a .gdb, the raster is clipped correctly.

Comment: That's unusual.  Were you specifying a .img or .tif extension for the raster output?

Comment: I was saving the output with a .tif extension into a .gdb.

Comment: There's the problem.  You cannot store .tif files in a file geodatabase--that uses its own raster format (i.e. no extension).  It is best to save directly to a folder (non-geodatabase) using a .img or .tif extension.